# Extract Pivot table until cells has the data

Tags: vba, excel

Sorry it may be a silly question i have gone through so many threads and even i tried however i am not getting what i needed and i am always confused about this if data is available in last row or last cell .

i am extracting the pivot table for which range is not specific sometimes i need to extract B24 , sometimes its in B50, i really don't know about the last row still i tried with this

```
Range("B24").Select
Selection.ShowDetail = True
```

it only works when i need to expand B24 but if its in B29 i need to change the code evrytime, please help

Comment: Are you just needing the last row in column B?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the last Row of the column B you can use the following:

```
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Sheets("YOUR SHEET NAME").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Range("B" & LastRow).ShowDetail = True
```

Last Row is a number so you could adjust it easily to get the beforelast row (LastRow -1)

Comment: Tried your code gives me an error  Run time Error 424 , Object Required   LastRow = mainWS.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row